# Wordpress menus disappeared and now menu locations will not update

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress site with 3 menus. All 3 menus were working the other day and then all of a sudden they disappeared. The menu items still exist, the menu locations exist and were working (have been working for weeks).

My problem is when I go to `Appearance > Menus > Manage Locations` and then check the appropriate location boxes and hit save it says they have been updated, but it does not save my changes.

I have tried disabling plugins and changing themes. I have also reinstalled some of the core files with no success. Please help me.

Comment: Do you got any error message, when trying to save?

Comment: No, I get a success message that it has been updated, but really the changes are not saved.

Comment: Do you have access to Wordpress DB?

Comment: I have access to everything.

Comment: If you want to debug it, please follow the instructions from here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-30-where-are-menu-items-and-relationships-stored?replies=3 to find your menus in DB and check what's wrong with them

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me this morning too. It was because I was running the latest nightly build of WordPress.

I got it working again by doing the following:

1. Deactivated the WordPress Beta Tester plugin
2. Downgraded to the latest official WordPress release (downloaded version 4.2.2 from https://wordpress.org/download/, and replaced the /wp-admin and /wp-includes directories as well as the files in the root directory).
3. Tried saving menus again --> worked.